# another layout probllem with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, joomla

I'm using joomla! for one of my websites. I had an HTML template, i modified it and turned it to a joomla! template.

I even included the java files, needed for IE, as IE is incompatible with some styles. now, I still can't view my website in IE<10.

about 20% of my visitors use IE, and i need to do something to fix this problem. any ideas?

and oh, here is my website address:

http://pichak-gallery.com

I have to mention that the HTML template works fine with any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation errors...
http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpichak-gallery.com%2F

You also have a BOM (Byte Order Mark). Use a proper editor such as Notepad++ or SuperEdi to remove any BOM in the *Save As...* dialog.

Anything before the Doctype with the exception of XML declaration is invalid including whitespace, remove that `div`.

Comment: tnx for introducing validator. the moment i repositioned DOCTYPE everything went fine.

Comment: No problem. If you serve your pages as XHTML (application/xhtml+xml) and use Firefox you will very quickly come across simple errors that you can fix in seconds instead of hours or days.

Answer (score 0):

First: have a look at your html in the [Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). There are several errors and warnings. Especially older IE versions have some problems with those warnings.

Second: You page throws an JS error this could also cause your problem.

Comment: tnx for introducing validator. the moment i repositioned DOCTYPE everything went fine.